# Cannot decode Home Assistant WebSocket data with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, home-assistant

This is a question specifically related to the Home Assistant system.

I'm trying to look up messages sent and received on WebSocket interfaces between frontend and the backend of Home Assistant. For this purpose I built a very basic HTTP proxy using node.js.

I manage to succesfully record the data sent and received on this WebSocket, but it's not decodable.

The code:

```js
var http = require('http')
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8123
    }
});

var proxyServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request Received");
    proxy.web(req, res);
});

proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    console.log("WS Upgrade Request Received");
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Data sent through WebSocket:', Buffer.from(data).toString());
        console.log('Data sent through WebSocket (JSON):', JSON.stringify(data, true, 2));
        console.log('Data represented as data to string: ', data.toString());
        // exception thrown
        //console.log('Data through JSON.parse(): ', JSON.parse(data));
        // exception thrown
        //console.log('Data represented as buffer: ', JSON.parse(Buffer.from(data)).toString());
    });
});
```

The problem is that it looks like the data I’m capturing here through the above function is not JSON decoded.

This is an example of output I’m getting:

```
Data sent through WebSocket: ��F��
Data sent through WebSocket (JSON): {
  "type": "Buffer",
  "data": [
    138,
    128,
    31,
    70,
    156,
    143
  ]
}
Data represented as data to string:  ��F��
```

According to the Home Assistant WebSocket documentation [here](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/api/websocket/): "Each API message is a JSON serialized object containing a type key.", so the above code shouldn't show this garbage. Or am I doing something wrong here?

I tried various JSON/Buffer decoding functions as documented above in the socket.on() function, but with no success.

Comment: “*I tried various JSON/Buffer decoding functions as documented above in the socket.on() function, but with no success.*” Can you share these attempts as part of your question in the form of [mre]s?

Comment: Quick guess: since "type" is buffer, you're supposed to turn the "data" property of your "data" JSON (confusing naming is a pain btw) into a buffer and then transform that into whichever format best suits your needs, tldr: create a result variable of whichever type data.type is and then fill it with data.data, then use that result variable for whatever you want. Right now, you're reading data (the json) as a string which of course gives you trash, you want data.data (as/in a Buffer.toString() ) instead.

Comment: Thanks for comments. The attempts I mentioned are those listed in the socket.on() function. Meanwhile I looked up this WS traffic in wireshark and it turned out that that what is seen here in the "data" object it is raw WS traffic including the WS header! It looks like to resolve this would be to use a different first argument of the socket.on(), so that it gives you the not the raw data, but the already stripped, actual message.

Comment: You're right, makes sens that it's only the header considering how short it is !